# Is there a way to change the Animator IK SetLookAtWeight slowly smooth?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]

public class IKControl : MonoBehaviour
{

    protected Animator animator;

    public bool ikActive = false;
    public Transform headObj = null;
    public Transform lookObj = null;

    private bool changeWeight = false;
    private float t = 0;
    private float value = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    //a callback for calculating IK
    void OnAnimatorIK()
    {
        if (animator)
        {

            //if the IK is active, set the position and rotation directly to the goal. 
            if (ikActive)
            {
                changeWeight = false;

                // Set the look target position, if one has been assigned
                if (lookObj != null)
                {
                    animator.SetLookAtWeight(1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
                    animator.SetLookAtPosition(lookObj.position);
                }
            }

            //if the IK is not active, set the position and rotation of the hand and head back to the original position
            else
            {
                changeWeight = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(changeWeight == true)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime / 5f;
            value = Mathf.Lerp(1f, 0f, t);

            animator.SetLookAtWeight(value);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use a flag and in the Update to change the value slowly so the SetLookAtWeight will take in this case 5 seconds just for testing.

But the SetLookAtWeight value is like jumping from 1 to 0 and not changing slowly from 1 to 0.
When I'm running the game and setting the bool flag ikActive to false the player head just change from the looking at mode to the idle mode at once directly.

And I want it to change slowly to the idle mode.

Answer (score 0):

You never reset your `t` value. After 5 seconds of gameplay, it will be greater than 1, and the Lerp will therefore always return the max value.

Try adding this line at the top of your `if (ikActive)` block
`t = 0f;`